# The selector "app-tool-tip" did not match any elements how do I fix this?

Tags: angular6, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I need to make a SIMPLE tool tip and I've implemented the following from here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

What I'm getting is this error: The selector "app-tool-tip" did not match any elements

Here's my tooltip component:

Tooltip Module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {NgbdTooltipComponent} from './tool-tip.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdTooltipComponent],
  exports: [NgbdTooltipComponent],
  bootstrap: [NgbdTooltipComponent]
})
export class NgbdTooltipModule {}
```

Tooltip Component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tool-tip',
  templateUrl: './tool-tip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tool-tip.component.scss']
})
export class NgbdTooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() toolTip: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Tooltip HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
        placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
        placement="right" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
        placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on bottom">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" 
        placement="left" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on left">
  Tooltip on left
</button>
```

This is my app-component.html

```
<div
  *ngIf="loading"
  class="loading d-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-md pt-3">

        <div class="loading__brand"></div>

        <h1 class="h3 my-3 text-center text-muted">Loading...</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<app-error-message *ngIf="showError" ng-class="{fade:doFade}" [errorMessage]="errorMessage"></app-error-message>
<app-tool-tip></app-tool-tip>
```

And this is being imported in my app.module.ts

```
import {NgbdTooltipModule} from './components/tool-tip/tool-tip.module';
```

This is my main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(NgbdTooltipModule)
  .then(ref => {
    // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
    if (window[<any>'ngRef']) {
      window['ngRef'].destroy();
    }
    window['ngRef'] = ref;

    // Otherwise, log the boot error
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

How do I fix this and why can't it find: app-tool-tip selector?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code provision for AppComponent & AppModule. You should bootstrap your AppModule (in main.ts), and import your NgbdTooltipModule into app.module.ts file. See below for an example. I hope it helps.

**Stackblitz Project:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbd-tooltips

```
// main.ts Main Entry

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule) // Bootstrap AppModule
.then(ref => {
  // Ensure Angular destroys itself on hot reloads.
  if (window[<any>'ngRef']) {
    window['ngRef'].destroy();
  }
  window['ngRef'] = ref;

  // Otherwise, log the boot error
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));


// app.module.ts - App Module: 

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdTooltipModule } from './ngbd-tooltip/ngbd-tooltip.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgbdTooltipModule // Import NgbdTooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


// ngbd-tooltip.module.ts - Tooltip Module:

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgbdTooltipComponent } from './ngbd-tooltip.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NgbdTooltipComponent], // Declare NgbdTooltipComponent
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [NgbdTooltipComponent] // Export NgbdTooltipComponent
})
export class NgbdTooltipModule { }
```